# How to run bash script on a Linux host, from Windows using plink

Tags: ruby, rvm, plink

I'm trying to run a simple bat file on Windows that will run a bash script on a remote Linux machine. The bash script is located on the Linux machine.

For example:
I'm trying to run this command in a batch file on Windows:

```
plink.exe -pw <password> root@<ip> bash -c "/root/script.sh"
```

Result:

- When running from windows the cmd is stuck forever
- When running the specific script (`/root/script.sh`) from the Linux machine it's working just fine.
- The script contain ruby code and I'm using RVM

Comment: Does the script require any interaction? What happens if you run `bash -c "/root/script.sh &"` instead?

Answer (score 0):

what do you see if you run the following? this will step through the script.

```
plink.exe -pw <password> root@<ip> bash -x "/root/script.sh"
```

also, be aware that the environment set up is different when you run remotely. you must make sure that all that is set up properly, such as PATH. so your script must say either /usr/bin/ruby instead of ruby, or add /usr/bin in the PATH, etc.

Or source a file that will set them up.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "/bin/sh: cannot execute binary file

Comment: ok, then change bash to /bin/bash, or /bin/sh and try again.

Comment: How should I write on windows? I'm running this from windows machine to linux machine

Comment: plink.exe -pw <password> root@<ip> /bin/bash -x "/root/script.sh"

Comment: plink.exe -pw <password> root@<ip> /bin/sh -x "/root/script.sh"

Comment: try quoting: plink.exe -pw <password> root@<ip> '/bin/bash -x "/root/script.sh"' but i think the double quotes are not needed. also in linux do which bash to make sure that bash is in the right place.

Comment: Now I'm getting- "no such file or directory: /bin/bash -x /root/script.sh". which bash returns /bin/bash

Comment: ah, then just remove all the quote. plink.exe -pw <password> root@<ip> /bin/bash -x /root/script.sh or if your script is executable and have #!/bin/bash as the first line, just plink.exe -pw <password> root@<ip> /root/script.sh

Comment: Now I'm getting: "stdin: is not a tty ./script/../config../preinitalizer.rb:5 Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with `gem install bundler` (RuntimeError)